# Submit form in view using IPagedList

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In the View I have this code:

```
`@model IPagedList<WebApplication3.Models.TopicAndDetails>
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
{...
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Topic)
...
}...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "QuestionAndAnswer", FormMethod.Post))
{
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topic) // I want to use it but I can't
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit">Submit</button>
}`
```

How can I submit the form to create new topic but I still using IPagedList . Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a bit hookey, but it's the simplest:

```
`@model IPagedList<WebApplication3.Models.TopicAndDetails>
 @{ string topic = ""; }
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
{...
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Topic)
        topic = item.Topic;
...
}..

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "QuestionAndAnswer", FormMethod.Post))
{
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => topic) 
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit">Submit</button>
}`
```

UPDATE (based on comments)
Becaue you are not submitting a `TopicAndDetails` object.  All you are submiting (and need) is a string named model.

```
 [HttpPost] 
 public ActionResult Index( string topic) 
 { 
    TopicAndDetails newtopic = new TopicAndDetails(); 
    newtopic.Topic = topic; 
    db.Topics.Add(newtopic); 
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```

Comment: I'm having  as your code, but model is still parameter of IPagedList<.TopicAndDetails> and when submit model in Controller is null . In the Controller I have this code
`       [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Index(    TopicAndDetails model)
        {
            TopicAndDetails topic = new TopicAndDetails();
            topic.Topic = model.Topic;
            db.Topics.Add(topic);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } `